# ElasticSearch sorting term aggregation buckets

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using term aggregation to get distinct records which mean each bucket will end up having one set of record but i could end up having a 5000 buckets total. what I want is those bucket results to be sorted by one of the properties of the document I am returning. my query looks:

```
                var response = await
               _elasticClient.SearchAsync<MyObject>(
                   s => s
                       .Index("myIndex")
                       .Type("myDocType")
                       .Size(0)
                       .Aggregations(a => a
                           .Terms("distinct_by_code", t => t
                           .Field("code.keyword")                                                                                      
                              .Aggregations(
                                  aa => aa.TopHits("distinct_hits", ds => ds                                                        
                                        .Source(src => src.Excludes(
                                                    ex => ex Field(f => f.Description)))
                                        .Size(1)
                                  )
                              )
                              .Size(5000)
                              //sort the buckets by price
                           )));
```

First of, each bucket could return more than one hits but i am only keeping one because I am selecting distinct by "code.keyword". The challenge is sorting all the hits in each buckets by a certain field so that a bucket with highest price will come first or I can pass a field I want it be sorted on.

Thanks

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve - get the highest price per `code.keyword`?

Comment: well what I actually want is sorting it in any direction with any of my properties in the tophits but I am using price as an example.